# How create a href through jquery .html and next use its event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, My problem is described below:

I have this javascript code in order to created a href in a table:

```
$('#table').html('<a name="example" class="one">One</a><a name="example" class="two">Two</a>');
```

And then I wanna know which `a` tag I pressed.... something like this:

```
$("a[name=example]").click(function(e) {
    var example= $(this).attr("class");
    alert(example); 
}
```

But this doesn't work...

Could you help me?

Thx 4 advance!

Comment: Read about [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to attach the click event to the fresh DOM (`a` tags) added dynamically to the page by your script :

```
$("#table").on('click','a[name=example]',function(e) {
  var example= $(this).attr("class");
  alert(example); 
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#table').html('<a name="example" class="one">One</a><br><a name="example" class="two">Two</a>');

$("#table").on('click','a[name=example]',function(e) {
  var example= $(this).attr("class");
  alert(example); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should do it.

```js
$("#table").on('click','a[name="example"]',function() {
    var example= $(this).attr("class");
    alert(example); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="table">
    <a name="example" class="one">One</a>
    <a name="example" class="two">Two</a>
  </div>
  </body>
  
  
</html>
```